# recurrence equation - closed form

Tags: algorithm, math

Could anyone please explain me briefly how we can get to a **closed-form** to solve a recurrence equation.

So, for an example:

T(n) = {3 if n = 1; T(n-1)+7 otherwise}

if n is large (n>1) then I do the following:

T(n) = (T(n-2) + 7) + 7 = T(n-2) + 2.7 = (T(n-3)+7) + 2.7 = T(n-3) + 3.7 and so on..
So for n>1 we ve got Tn = T(n - i) + i.7

How do we calculate the same thing for n=1 and most importantly how can I come up with a closed form??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  The expansion would be

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + 7
     = T(n-2) + 7 + 7 = T(n-2) + 2*7
     = T(n-i) + i*7

...  when i = (n-1) you get

     = T(1) + (n-1)*7
     = 3 + (n-1)*7
     = 3 + 7*n - 7
     = 7*n - 4   <---------
```

Comment: ok. I understand but can you please expand on "...  when i = (n-1) you get" I really don't get what's the concept/principle behind it. I am very confused. What do we have to proof exactly? Thanks

Comment: plug `n-1` into `i` and you're left with the next equation.

Comment: ok but why do we do the rest T(1) + (n-1)*7 ...What's the idea. Why do we have to calculate it in that way when n = 1 and n > n combined?? Or possibly if you can paste some link where  I can read more about that would be great. thanks